# Lumen 5.8 Auth attempt does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm new to Lumen and building a RESTful API and I got stuck for how many hours now because Auth::attempt is not working. I've been searching for any answers but all the results are only Laravel not Lumen.

So I created a AuthController and login method to authenticate user but I got an error.

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if( !Auth::attempt($credentials) ) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);
        }
}
```

This is the error: "Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist."

Anyone can help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following:

```
   if (!Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);
    }
```

The method is only available for routes which are using the web middleware, could you check that out?
You may need to edit your `config/auth` file.

Comment: Ok I'll try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lumen Passport Setup:

```
composer require dusterio/lumen-passport
```

Enable the app and auth service providers in bootstrap/app.php

add the following service providers in the bootstrap file

```
$app->register(Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Dusterio\LumenPassport\PassportServiceProvider::class);
```

replace the contents inside the boot function of the auth service provider in /app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider with:

```
LumenPassport::routes($this->app->router);
```

Run php artisan migrate

run php artisan passport:install

Then follow this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#issuing-access-tokens

remeber the lumen version does not have views or routes for authorising access you have to build them seperatly on your client.

Comment: I forgot to add make a auth config file enabled in bootstrap and replace token in api to passport and set api as default and enable facades and eloquent in bootstrap file